# Converting time to HH:MM

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I currently have a float value like 12.5, 4, 17.5. I want these to correspond to the times 12:30PM, 4:00AM, and 5:30PM.

I've currently achieved something close to this with the hack

```
if (time > 12.5) {
        time = abs(roundedValue - 12);
        [lab setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:00PM",(int)time]];
    } else {
        [lab setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:00AM",(int)time]];
    }
```

But I know this is bad practice. What's a better way to convert these numbers to times?

Comment: Hint:  An hour is 60 minutes.

Comment: so basically your floats are hours?

Comment: (You could convert you time value to an NSTimeInteval and add that to the NSDate value for 12 midnight, then use NSDateFormatter, but I suspect that's beyond your comprehension.)

Comment: @HotLicks beyond my comprehension haha. wow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just basic math, you have a value, say 12.5, which consists of a number of hours, 12, and a fraction of an hour, 0.5. There are 60 mins in an hour so the number of minutes is just the fraction times 60.

If you want to use the 12 hour clock there is a small quirk, hours > 12 need to be reduced by 12 but noon (12) is pm and midnight (0 or 24) is am. So the test for am/pm is not the same test as whether to subtract 12.

Here is one way to do it (with minimal checking):

```
NSString *hoursToString(double floatHours)
{
   int hours = trunc(floatHours); // number of hours
   int mins = round( (floatHours - hours) * 60 ); // mins is the fractional part times 60
   // rounding might result in 60 mins...
   if (mins == 60)
   {
      mins = 0;
      hours++;
   }
   // we haven't done a range check on floatHours, also the above can add 1, so reduce to 0 -> 23
   hours %= 24;

   // if you are using 24 hour clock you can finish here and format to the two values

   BOOL pm = hours >= 12; // 0 - 11 = am, 12 - 23 = pm
   if (hours > 12) hours -= 12; // 13 - 23 -> 1 -> 11

   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d %s", hours, mins, (pm ? "pm" : "am")];
}
```

You call this simply as:

```
hoursToString(13.1) // returns 1:06 pm
```

No need to use `NSDate` *et al*.

HTH

Comment: I like this answer much better. Minor note - the use of `trunc` is a bit pointless since the conversion from `double` to `int` will do it implicitly.

Comment: The OP didn't state what the possible range of values are but it should be noted that a little extra logic is needed if `floatHours` can ever be greater than `24.0`.

Comment: @rmaddy - I knew someone would call me out on the lack of checking ;-) I had just come back with a better version when I found your comment, edited the question. BTW I used `trunc` to make it obvious and contrast with `round` - and I've now dealt with the possible 60 mins that might produce.

Comment: I didn't get a chance to finish posting earlier, but mine is similar enough to yours that I will just comment instead that `modf()` might be a simpler way to separate the hours and minutes. No rounding problem.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - `modf` could be used instead of `trunc` and the `floatHours - hours` to obtain the whole and fractional hours respectively. I considered that but the use of a pointer to a double, as `modf` requies, seemed unnecessary complication for questionable gain for this answer. The use of `round` above is to handle the fractional minutes so values >= 0.5 go to the next minute (and this is why the test for 60 is required, so say 5h 59m 40s is displayed as 6:00 and not 5:60)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing the following:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:now];
[components setHour:0];

NSDate *today10am = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSDate *newDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:roundedValue*60*60 sinceDate:today10am];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm aa"];
[lab setText:[dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate]];
```

Sorry Hot Licks, guess this was within my comprehension.

Comment: This is a really inefficient way to covert a decimal hour value into a simple hours and minutes string.

Comment: Note that the above will fail on some phones if you do not set the locale properly.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the following -

```
NSNumber *time = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([yourTime doubleValue] - 3600)];
NSTimeInterval interval = [time doubleValue];
NSDate *yourDate = [NSDate date];
yourDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSLog(@"result: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```

Comment: Sorry, but that code makes no sense.  Why do you make `time` be an NSNumber?  Why do you subtract 3600 rather than multiplying by 3600?  Why do you initialize `yourDate` and then immediately overwrite it with another value?  Why do you use a 24-hour date format when the OP indicated he wanted 12-hour format?

Comment: (I'll grant you that it is clever to use the 1970 reference date vs developing a midnight today reference.  But you need to make sure that the date formatter timezone is set to GMT, or the displayed values will be off.)

Comment: What makes you so confident making time to NSNumber not required? Have u even tried running this. That's overconfident. Wrong use of voting down rights.

Comment: I count 4 bugs in 7 lines of code and you don't think it should be downvoted??

Comment: No. They r not bugs at all. You think they r bugs. Where is the thing documented? This thing is working and working good. Some things may be redundant. But that's how starters and learners learn. If you can't encourage, don't discourage either.

Comment: If you think that works (per the OP's requirements) you're seriously deluding yourself.  (What time is displayed if you input 10.5?)

Comment: I'm sure u think so. You are already getting judgmental showing others here are deluded and you are the only one smart.